# Submission error! response.header is not a function in nest-fastify graphql

Tags: graphql, header, nestjs, fastify

I need set header autorization client. But have error in my Mutation "Submission error! response.header is not a function".

my main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  await app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ stopAtFirstError: true }));
  await app.register(fastifyCookie, {
    secret: 'secret',
  });
  await app.listen(3500);
}
```

my resolver

```
@Mutation((returns) => AccessToken, { nullable: true })
  async registerUser(
    @Args('createUser') createUserInput: CreateUserInput,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: FastifyReply,
  ): Promise<{ token: string }> {
    const token = await this.userService.registerUser(createUserInput);

    await response.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    return { token: token };
  }
```

Comment: Why are you returning an authorization header? And why are you accessing the response through `@Res()` inside a resolver?

Comment: i need save token in authorization header for client

Comment: I'll be honest, I've never seen an `Authorization` header on the _response_. But I guess if it works for you it works for you. Why do you get the response from `@Res()` though? You should get it through the `@Context()` via `ctx.res` so long as `res` is added to the `context` in the `GraphQLModule`'s options

Comment: Then it turns out to send a token from the server in the response body?

Comment: I'm just learning. I did not understand the principle of operation. I have already solved this issue, thank you